# Is making code more modular in Android selector XML code possible?

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, android-selector

I have the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
                <shape>
                    <corners android:radius="@dimen/rounded_corner_standard" />
                    <gradient android:angle="90"
                        android:endColor="#E2E2E2" android:startColor="#BABABA" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp">
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
                    <corners android:radius="@dimen/rounded_corner_standard" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item>
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
                <shape>
                    <corners android:radius="@dimen/rounded_corner_standard" />
                    <gradient android:angle="90"
                        android:endColor="#E2E2E2" android:startColor="#BABABA" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp">
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
                    <corners android:radius="@dimen/rounded_corner_standard" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

From the code, you would notice there are some identical piece of codes as below with only one different indicated using **THE ONLY DIFFERENT**

```
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
                <shape>
                    <corners android:radius="@dimen/rounded_corner_standard" />
                    <gradient android:angle="90"
                        android:endColor="#E2E2E2" android:startColor="#BABABA" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp">
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="@color/*THE ONLY DIFFERENT*"/>
                    <corners android:radius="@dimen/rounded_corner_standard" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
```

Is there a way I could group this code like making a module function, and pass in a parameter of my color... Either using include or whatever approaches possible? In case I would like to change something, I don't need to change both side.

Comment: if you dont want to repeat the code use a custom `StateListDrawable` class (class extending `SLD`)

Comment: Thanks. I guess you are asking me to get back to Java and programatically handle this. Thanks, that's one possible way.